# transform HTML tags within XML using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following source XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<employees>
<employee>
<html-content>
<p>This is the first text.<br/>
With multiple lines.<br/>
And maybe one more.</p>
<p>This is the second text.<br/>
With multiple lines.<br/>
And maybe one more.</p>
</html-content>
</employee>
</employees>
```

I want to use XSLT to transform it into this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<employees>
<employee>
<info>
<text>
<content>This is the first text.</content>
<br/>
<content>With multiple lines.</content>
<br/>
<content>And maybe one more.</content>
</text>
<text>
<content>This is the second text.</content>
<br/>
<content>With multiple lines.</content>
<br/>
<content>And maybe one more.</content>
</text>
</info>
</employee>
</employees>
```

In summary

- map `<p>` to `<text>` (that's the easy part)
- make a new `<content>` every time there is a `<br/>` encounter (that's where I struggle).

So far I have this XSLT, but that just puts all the `<br/>` at the end, so that does not really help me.

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"   
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">
<employees>
<xsl:for-each select="employees/employee">
<employee>
<info>
<xsl:apply-templates select="html-content"/>
</info>
</employee>
</xsl:for-each>
</employees>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
<text>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="br"/>
</text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br">
<br-found/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results in:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
   <employee>
      <info>
         <text>This is the first text.
With multiple lines.
And maybe one more.<br-found/>
            <br-found/>
         </text>
         <text>This is the second text.
With multiple lines.
And maybe one more.<br-found/>
            <br-found/>
         </text>
      </info>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: Do you really need to keep the `<br/>` divider in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="html-content">
    <info>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <text>
        <xsl:for-each select="text()">
            <content>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </content>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code you can update template for `p` as:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </text>
</xsl:template>
```

and add an extra template as below:

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <content>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </content>
</xsl:template>
```